# Is it possible to get the height of the buffer *including* word wrap?

Tags: vimscript

I can grab the number of lines of a buffer with `line("$")`, but this does not take into account if my terminal is small and I have `set wrap` and some lines wrap.

I wonder if it is possible to query this (greater) line count value? Basically it would be the # of times that you could `gj` from the top of the file (plus one). That's not a practical way to calculate it, neither is doing math based on the window dimension `winwidth()` and the buffer contents themselves.

Comment: for my application (sizing for small files to get their windows to auto-size upon opening) i actually can use `gj` in a loop to scan the height. it's very very ugly, but it will not be slow because i will always terminate it within 200 steps

Comment: Don't count (pun!) too much on any number of wrapped lines you may find, as it will change if you modify a Vim setting such as `showbreak`, `number` (with `relativenumber`), `foldcolumn` (or when using signs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to employ `strdisplaywidth()` for this job. It takes things like number, fold and sign columns into account as well as `&linebreak`, `&showbreak` and `&breakindent` option effects. Problem is that you still have to somehow calculate width of the window available for text (i.e. exclude widths of number, fold and sign columns): `strdisplaywidth()` returns how many display cells are occupied, but it does not tell you how many display cells there are. The following code should do this:

```
function WinTextWidth()
    let winwidth = winwidth(0)
    let winwidth -= (max([len(line('$')), &numberwidth]) * (&number || &relativenumber))
    let winwidth -= &foldcolumn
    redir => signs
    execute 'silent sign place buffer=' . bufnr('%')
    redir END
    if signs !~# '^\n---[^\n]*\n$'
        let winwidth -= 2
    endif
    return winwidth
endfunction
function LineCount(...)
    let startlnr = get(a:000, 0, 1)
    let endlnr = get(a:000, 1, line('$'))
    let numlines = 0
    let winwidth = WinTextWidth()
    for lnr in range(startlnr, endlnr)
        let lwidth = strdisplaywidth(getline(lnr))
        let numlines += max([(lwidth - 1) / winwidth + 1, 1])
    endfor
    return numlines
endfunction
```

`strdisplaywidth(getline(lnr))` may also be replaced with `virtcol([lnr, '$']) - 1`, this should be slightly faster and more compatible with older Vim versions.

Comment: Thanks, this has prompted me to learn about `showbreak` and `breakindent` which do work quite nicely along with `linebreak` to make thin windows much more readable!

Comment: I think this is perhaps possible to enhance to use for a window which is not the current window. But for right now my script does still use the technique of moving around with `wincmd j` and so forth so these functions are sufficient.

Comment: This incorrectly counts lines that are empty (adding zero to `numlines`). I will edit when I have a code fix.

Comment: I have applied the code change that makes it work well now. It does appear to (in my very few test cases) correctly determine the height. However I am really confused about how it is able to magically take into account the `linebreak` contributions. It must internally be aware of the window width and using that... it would be probably much more sensible if this function just went and did that division for us instead of giving us this otherwise useless column count.

Comment: @StevenLu This function uses exactly the same code that is used by Vim to draw line on screen (you may see that f_linebreak from eval.c and win_line from screen.c both use win_lbr_chartabsize, though f_linebreak has a few more layers on top of that). And no, *that* internal function does not return a number of lines. Basically by introducing strdisplaywidth() Bram provided access to some rather internal function and I have no idea how much work it would be if this function did not exist: it existed at least since 7.0.1.

Comment: @StevenLu Last edit regarding folds 1. did not take into account that in this case fold is 1 line 2. if you want to proceed with gj-based definition you need to also take into account `&foldopen` and solution becomes really weird and 3. you cannot do this with a `:for` cycle, this should be `:while` cycle with `lnr` able to increment not only by 1.

Comment: Hmm I was just adapting the original function you posted which used the `for lnr in range(startlnr, endlnr)` construction. Yes I think there are still flaws with this current code. If the top folded line is over-long it's wrong since when it is closed it would not wrap.

Comment: My use of `gj` to define the problem was mostly to illustrate that some lines require `gj` more than once e.g. take up more physical space depending on the width of the window and a whole host of options as we see here. The real purpose is to set the height of the window (if file small enough) so it will fit perfectly.

Comment: @StevenLu In any case it is better to use `while` cycle here. Though I have mistaken what exactly `foldclosed*()` do: do not remember which exactly, but some fold function required to be run only on the first line of the fold.

Comment: Ah, your comment makes more sense then.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that vim does not store the wrapped lines, it only displays those you have here. If you really want to do it you can do it a little bit more efficiently than using gj. The idea is to go to the beginning of the page, go to the end of the displayed window and use winline(), which gives you the displayed line number of the window and then scroll the page with z+.

```
function! CountLine()
  normal! gg
  let l:count = 0
  while 1
    normal! L$
    let l:count = l:count + winline()
    if line('.') == line('$')
      break
    else
      normal! z+
    endif
  endwhile
  return l:count
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the live buffer of the window is available in the python interface. This means I can use python to iterate the lines and compute for myself how many times each line wraps over, and then this can be summed to obtain an estimate of what the real working height of the buffer in the window is.

Here's an example of how you'd extricate some of this data from vimscript. I wrote this code here to inspect the data structures available inside `vim.windows`:

```
python << EOF                                                                
for win in vim.windows:                                                          
    print ", ".join([str(x) for x in [win.col, win.row, win.width, win.height]]);
    windir = dir(win)                                                            
    print 'dir: ' + str(windir)                                                  
    for method in windir:                                                        
        attr = getattr(win, method)                                              
        if method == 'buffer':                                                   
            print '    buffer: length ' + str(len(attr))                         
            print '    buffer[0]: ' + str(attr[0])                               
        elif method[0] != '_':                                                   
            print '    ' + method + ': ' + str(attr)                             
EOF
```

Some rather annoying things to keep in mind:

1. this height i'm talking about depends on the width of the vim window (when wrapping)
2. have to correctly deal with tabs and other chars which take up more space. I am unable to think of anything other than the Tab that has these properties (and even if I did use Unicode characters which I rarely do, I'm pretty sure i've never seen any that are supposed to take up more than one column), and with Tab the semantics seem pretty simple, it will take up exactly `&tabstop` columns.
3. the width of the window *includes* the numberline. The numberline's width is dependent on the line count of the buffer, but also at least as wide as `&numberwidth`.
4. the width of the window *also* includes the sign gutter. Luckily this is only ever a width of 0 or 2, right now all i can figure out is we need to use `redir` with `sign place [bufnr]` to find out for sure about the presence of this sign column.
5. the type of wrapping (`set linebreak`) affects this (Maybe we replicate this wrap-by-word on the python side...)

There may be yet other factors that lead Vim to need more or less space than what we would naively compute in this way. Hopefully `linebreak` is one of the few remaining Vim features (maybe, hopefully it's the only one) that affect this. I can confirm that `conceal` does not interfere with wrapping offsets.

Obtaining the height this way should be many times more performant than using vimscript techniques, which invariably result in a lot more Vim frontend logic to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do it:

```
" Calculates the number of columns and the number of screen lines the given
" array of lines will take up, taking account of wrapping.
function! s:screen_lines(lines)
  let [_virtualedit, &virtualedit]=[&virtualedit, 'all']
  let cursor = getcurpos()
  normal! g$
  let available_width = virtcol('.')
  call setpos('.', cursor)
  let &virtualedit=_virtualedit
  let width = min([max(map(copy(a:lines), 'strdisplaywidth(v:val)')), available_width])

  if exists('*reduce')
    let height = reduce(a:lines, { acc, val -> acc + strdisplaywidth(val) / width + (strdisplaywidth(val) % width == 0 ? 0 : 1) }, 0)
  else
    let height = eval(join(map(copy(a:lines), 'strdisplaywidth(v:val) / width + (strdisplaywidth(v:val) % width == 0 ? 0 : 1)'), '+'))
  endif

  return [width, height]
endfunction

echom s:screen_lines(getline(1, '$'))
```